# Docker with App_Data volume?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-volume

I'm trying out Docker on a Synology with .NET Core, but I'm having some issue with disk access.

In my ASP.NET Core app I build and persist some data during the app-Startup if not existing allready. But when running the app in Docker and requesting it from a browser I don't get any data in this folders, so I suspect that the folder is not found or is not accessible.

How do I setup my Docker Image to find and have access to this folder? What account is a Docker request thread executing with? Do I have to add read/write access for this account to this folder manually? I have mounted a volume but I'm not sure what to enter for the mount path? Is this correct?

```
/docker/mywebapp/App_Data /App_Data
```

Is it a problem that source dir is inside the docker-image-path itself?

**Update**

The problem was not really with disk access. I had some code that depended on being able to check if the request ip was local and Docker is using another private network ip-range so I had to fix that first.

But now when running the app, which is working and apparently saving data, I don't get where the files are saved? The folder I pointed to, my App_Data-folder, is still empty. Are the files stored elsewhere? And it seem to work fine even without a mounted Docker Volume. How is that possible?

Comment: when you say the source dir is inside the dockerimage path itself, what do you mean?

Comment: I was assuming that the mapped path is rooted to the image folder. If the source path is inside the image itself, where my app binaries are, maybe that's bad for some reason... But I have probably just misunderstood how this works...